# Using scanner to read string from text file and then print out

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file which has the string, - `"!-   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ==========="` in it as you can see in the code below. IF the text file contains this string I need to read it from the text file and then print it out again. The problem is I cant work out why my code is not printing it.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Anton/Pictures/1 x geotransform0.5m shading.txt");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

            while(scan.hasNext()){
                String str = scan.next();

                if(str == "!-   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ==========="){
                    System.out.print(str);
                }
            }
            scan.close();
        }   
}
```

Comment: When using a debugger, what is `str` when you get to the `if` statement?

Comment: Use equals() method of String object instead ==.

Comment: This looks bad `str == `. Take a look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Also `next()` will return only one word. You probably need to use `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code, scanner next gives just a word use nextLine instead to read whole line..

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            String str1 = scan.nextLine();

                if(str1.equals("!-   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ==========="))
                    System.out.println(str1);
                scan.close();
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it, I'm pretty new to Java so im just learning all these ins and outs cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use  this

```
if(str.equals("!-   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ===========")){
            System.out.print(str);
        }
```

instead of

```
if(str == "!-   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ==========="){
            System.out.print(str);
        }
```